# Django-admin + dijit-editor : An un-necessary extra field At the top of the page

Tags: python, django, django-admin, dojo

I have added a dojo rtf editor to a django admin page using the instructions from  this blog post ([Using Dojo Rich Editor with Django's Admin](http://lazutkin.com/blog/2011/mar/13/using-dojo-rich-editor-djangos-admin/)).

The problem is that there appears and extra rtf editor at the top of the page .[image: ScreenShot]
How do I get rid of this ?

The Source Code for the project can be found at [gautamk/QPaperGenerator-Django - GitHub.](https://github.com/gautamk/QPaperGenerator-Django)

Comment: How do you initiate the rich-text editor? By CSS selectors?

Comment: @StumpyJoePete: I haven't been working with that project for a long time , So I forgot about verifying your answer. sorry . I will accept it because You are the only one who answered it . Thank you

Comment: @GautamK Thanks! Hope your project turned out alright. :-)

Comment: It was a small project that I had made in 2 nights for my college, I don't know what has happened to it since I graduated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that all `textarea` elements are getting turned into dijit editor widgets. The code at fault is in editor.js:

```
var textareas = dojo.query("textarea");
if(textareas && textareas.length){
  ...
  textareas.instantiate(dijit.Editor, {...});
}
```

As you can see, the query selects all `textareas`, not just the ones you want. Now, I have no idea why there's a text area up at the top of your screen to begin with, but presumably it's getting hit by this query too. To fix the problem, try a more specific query. For instance something like one of these:

```
dojo.query("#id_question"); // Only the question field
dojo.query("#id_comments"); // Only the comments field
dojo.query(".vLargeTextField"); // All the large-ish admin text widgets
```